# Error con formulario phpmailer Deprecated: Function split

Tags: php, phpmailer

Quiero enviar un formulario a un correo personal, utilice un ejemplo de phpmailer que ví en este foro, y funcionó, se envía el correo, pero al mostrar el echo con la confirmación, primero aparecen un par de mensajes, que no quiero que aparezcan pero no sé como quitarlos, yo solo mando a pantalla el mensaje "Hemos recibido tu mensaje..." Y si ya que el correo llega bien, me interesa quitar esos mensajes del echo

[image: Captura de pantalla con el error]

> Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /.../public_html/remodelacion/pcontacto/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1432
>
> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /.../public_html/remodelacion/pcontacto/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line
> 472

Les dejo el código php que estoy utilizando pero no creo que tenga mucho que ver con el error.

```
<?php
$nombre = $empresa = $correot = $asunto = $mensaje = $captcha = $para = NULL;
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$empresa = $_POST["empresa"];
$correo = $_POST["correo"];
$asunto = $_POST["asunto"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
$captcha = $_POST["captcha"];
$para = 'nombre@midominio.com';

$keySecret = "6LfFFi4UAAAAA..........................";
$verificacion = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$keySecret}&response={$captcha}");
$respGoogle = json_decode($verificacion);

if($respGoogle->success == true){
      require"phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";

      $mail = new PHPMailer;
      $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
      $mail->From = $correo;
      $mail->FromName = $nombre;
      $mail->addAddress($para, "NOMBRE");
      $mail->addReplyTo($correo,$nombre);
      $mail->addBCC("micorreo@outlook.com");
      $mail->isHTML(true);
      $mail->Subject = $asunto;
      $mail->Body = "
              <h1>Correo de Prueba</h1>

              Nombre: $nombre<br />
              Empresa: $empresa<br />
              Email: $correo <br />
              Mensaje: $mensaje <br />

      "; 
    //Aquí es donde aparece el error, al enviar el mensaje
    if(!$mail->send()) {                   
        echo "Mensaje no Enviado vuelva a intentar";
    } else {
        echo "<b>Hemos recibido tu mensaje, te contestaremos lo más pronto posible</b>";
    } 
}
else if($respGoogle->success == false){
    echo "Error. Google no validó el captcha :(";
}
?>
```

Comment: Necesitas actualizar [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) a su **última versión**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## El problema

**Es grave y es crítico.**

Los mensajes de error indican que tu instalación de PHPMailer no está actualizada.

En 2016, Dawid Golunski descubrió dos fallos de seguridad  en PHPMailer, reportados en legalhackers:

- Uno fue reportado el 25.12.2016, e indica lo siguiente: [PHPMailer < 5.2.18 Remote Code Execution](https://legalhackers.com/advisories/PHPMailer-Exploit-Remote-Code-Exec-CVE-2016-10033-Vuln.html). Es decir, que en versiones anteriores a la 5.2.18 se puede ejecutar código remoto. Se trata por tanto de un fallo de seguridad crítico.
- El otro fue reportado en fecha 27.12.2016, e indica lo siguiente: [PHPMailer < 5.2.20 Remote Code Execution (0day Patch Bypass/exploit)](https://legalhackers.com/advisories/PHPMailer-Exploit-Remote-Code-Exec-CVE-2016-10045-Vuln-Patch-Bypass.html) Se trata de un fallo parecido al primero y también crítico.

Ambos fallos fueron tratado en la Wiki de PHPMailer en Github: [About the CVE 2016 10033 and CVE 2016 10045 vulnerabilities](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/About-the-CVE-2016-10033-and-CVE-2016-10045-vulnerabilities)

---

## La solución

**Es urgente**

El software no actualizado puede resultar peligroso para tu sitio web, ya que usuarios mal intencionados pueden aprovechar vulnerabilidades en esos archivos para introducir código malicioso en tu sitio.

Por lo tanto es urgente actualizar tu versión de PHPMailer.

### ¿Cómo actualizar?

Sobre la actualización, todo está explicado por los creadores en GitHub: [PHPMailer Upgrading](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/UPGRADING.md)

Hay varias maneras.

#### Opción 1: usar `composer` (recomendada)

La más recomendada por los creadores es usar `composer`:

> Le recomendamos que cargue PHPMailer a través de composer, utilizando
>   su autocargador estándar, que probablemente no necesitará cargar si ya
>   lo está utilizando, pero en caso de que no lo esté, tendrá que hacerlo
>   usted mismo:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

#### Opción 2: Manualmente (no recomendada)

> Si no está usando `composer`, puede cargar las clases manualmente,
>   dependiendo de lo que esté usando:

```
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';
require 'src/Exception.php';
```

La ventaja de usar `composer` es que te mantendrá PHPMailer actualizado.

Si lo haces manualmente tendrás que estar pendiente de las futuras actualizaciones.

Sobre todo cuando se empieza en PHP lo de `composer` puede sonar a chino, pero no es tan complicado instalarlo en tu servidor si no lo está y luego todo es más fácil.

Cualquier duda sobre [composer](/questions/tagged/composer) la puedes buscar/plantear también aquí en SO.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por la información, pero entonces tengo otra duda, el error es con mi código o con el archivo que cargue de phpmailer? o es error del servidor. Yo pensaba que era un error precisamente de la versión pero no encontré en donde descargar la versión más reciente de phpmailer. Y si realmente no tengo gran idea de lo que es composer.

Comment: El error no es tu código en sí, aunque puede que, al actualizar, tengas que cambiar alguna línea del código. Como explico en la respuesta el gran problema es que, al tener archivos desactualizados tu sitio es vulnerable. En el apartado **¿Cómo actualizar?** quise explicar brevemente las dos formas de hacerlo: mediante composer o descargando los archivos nuevos de PHPMailer desde github. Si quieres puedes plantear una nueva pregunta _¿Cómo puedo actualizar PHPMailer?_. Creo que de esa forma tendrás diversas respuestas más detalladas.