# direccionar a una pagina con php

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy haciendo un formulario que al enviar los datos por correo si estos son enviados exitosamente me regrese al home de la página pero al hacerlo me da el siguiente error:

> Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/new_arreglosya/class.phpmailer.php on line 1918

Estoy trabajando con PHP y la clase PHPMailer, cabe destacar que el correo llega perfectamente a la dirección de correo de envio pero no me direcciona a la página de inicio.

Este es el código que utilizo para redireccionar:

```
$data = enviar_correo($nombre, $direccion, $celular, $correo, $servicio, $precio);
if($data){
    header("Location: http://localhost/new_arreglosya/");
} else {
    echo "No enviado";
}
```

Comment: Te sugiero que para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida, te tomes un segundo antes de enviarla, para leerla y saber si esta bien redactada y bien escrita.

Comment: Tu phpmailer posiblemente este desactualizado, mira esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101042/error-con-formulario-phpmailer-deprecated-function-split

Comment: Como bien dice @LeviArista, el problema es con PHPMailer, no con tu código de redirección.

Comment: Ok estoy buscando la nueva version de PHPMailer para trabajar con ella